# Azure resource group move does not complete. Can not take any action on either resource group

Tags: azure

I tried to move all the resources in a resources group to another and now both resource groups are pretty much inoperable. `

"value": [
{
"id": "/subscriptions/b14e1f80-b3a3-49aa-9f13-7a8d51cbbac3/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-eastus",
"name": "cloud-shell-storage-eastus",
"location": "eastus",
"properties": {
"provisioningState": "Succeeded"
}
},
{
"id": "/subscriptions/b14e1f80-b3a3-49aa-9f13-7a8d51cbbac3/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG",
"name": "NetworkWatcherRG",
"location": "eastus",
"properties": {
"provisioningState": "Succeeded"
}
},
{
"id": "/subscriptions/b14e1f80-b3a3-49aa-9f13-7a8d51cbbac3/resourceGroups/azuremolchapter19",
"name": "azuremolchapter19",
"location": "eastus",
"properties": {
"provisioningState": "MovingResources"
}
},
{
"id": "/subscriptions/b14e1f80-b3a3-49aa-9f13-7a8d51cbbac3/resourceGroups/MC_azuremolchapter19_azuremol_eastus",
"name": "MC_azuremolchapter19_azuremol_eastus",
"location": "eastus",
"tags": {},
"properties": {
"provisioningState": "MovingResources"
}
}
]
}

Cannot delete or any other operation.

"error": {
"code": "ResourcesBeingMoved",
"message": "The resource group 'MC_azuremolchapter19_azuremol_eastus' is being updated and cannot perform this operation."

Cannot find a solution. Can someone help?
}

Answer (score 0):

I logged in a this morning and was able to delete the resource groups. Don't know where to find any logs outside of the subscription activity log where I could find any information as to what happened.